# Need to make same javascript function in python

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I'm trying to use some API with Python. Can't translate this JavaScript function:

```
const requestUrl = '/api/v1/account/balance' //add

const data = {
  request: requestUrl,
  currency: "ETH",
  nonce: parseInt(Date.now().toString() / 1000)
};
const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
const payload = new Buffer(stringifiedData).toString('base64')
console.log(payload);
```

the outcome result:
`eyJyZXF1ZXN0IjoiL2FwaS92MS9hY2NvdW50L2JhbGFuY2UiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IkVUSCIsIm5vbmNlIjoxNTU5MTQzOTI2fQ==`

I'm trying to do same with python3:

```
from flask import Flask, json
app = Flask(__name__)
timestam = datetime.datetime.now()
timenow = int (timestam.strftime("%s"))
nonce = str(timenow)

@app.route("/")
def func1():
    reuquestUrl= '/api/v1/account/balance'
    data = {
       "request":reuquestUrl, 
       "currency":"ETH",
       "nonce":nonce
   }
   stringfieldData=json.dumps(data)
   payload = str(base64.b64encode(b'stringfieldData'))          
   return payload
```

it returns `b'c3RyaW5nZmllbGREYXRh'` or something like this. 
I also tried jsonify with almost same result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you are b64 encoding the string `'strigifiedData'` itself, instead of the contents of the variable with that name (because `b'stringfieldData'` is a `bytes` object literal)

in addition, b64 encode returns a `bytes` object, so if you want to return a string, you need to `.decode()` it.

try this please, let me know if it helped:

```py
def func1():
    reuquestUrl= '/api/v1/account/balance'
    data = {"request":reuquestUrl, "currency":"ETH","nonce":nonce}
    stringfieldData=json.dumps(data)
    payload = base64.b64encode(stringfieldData.encode())
    return payload.decode()
```

Comment: nope, result was "TypeError: string argument without an encoding".
    But i managed to find right way:
    def func1():
        reuquestUrl= '/api/v1/account/balance'
       data = {"request":reuquestUrl, 
       "currency":"ETH",
       "nonce":nonce}
        data = json.dumps(data, separators = (',', ':'))
        payload = base64.b64encode(data.encode())
        payload = payload.decode()
        return payload

Comment: OK my bad, checked this on Python 2. I've edited my answer to fix that (using `.encode()` on the string instead of a direct cast to `bytes`)

Comment: Thank you so much, hope it will help to someone more.